# How to unmarshal xml with repetitive entries using JAXB and Spring

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb

I have to convert `xml` to `Map<String,String>`. I have following XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Environments>
  <Environment Name="A" URIPath="http://a.com" />
  <Environment Name="B" URIPath="http://b.com" />
  <Environment Name="C" URIPath="http://c.com" />
</Environments>
```

I tried multiple ways but eneded with `Class has two properties of the same name "URIPath"`. What is the right design for unmarshalling this XML?

**UPDATE:**

Using provided solution #1 I am getting :

```
Class has two properties of the same name "environments"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.util.List app.model.Environments.getEnvironments()
        at app.model.Environments
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.util.List app.model.Environments.environments
        at app.model.Environments
Class has two properties of the same name "URIPath"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String app.model.Environment.getURIPath()
        at app.model.Environment
        at public java.util.List app.model.Environments.environments
        at app.model.Environments
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.lang.String app.model.Environment.URIPath
        at app.model.Environment
        at public java.util.List app.model.Environments.environments
        at app.model.Environments
] with root cause
```

Comment: Generally, you will get that error when you have the field annotated, and also have matching getters and setters for the field. The framework will treat both the field and the property (getter/setter) and attributes. You can either annotate the getter instead of the field or annotation the class with `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`

Comment: Updated my answer. The posted examples are working code. The error you get is most likely because you added getters/setters and that's why JAXB complains that you have multiple properties with the same name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1) Unmarshal a collection of `Environment` instances with 2 fields: `Name` and `URIPath`. You can build the map later if you want to from the collection.

2) Use a custom [`XmlAdapter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html) which properly creates the map from the collection.

### Elaborating Solution #1

This solution needs the following classes:

```
class Environments {
    @XmlElement(name = "Environment")
    public List<Environment> environments;
}

class Environment {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Name")
    public String Name;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "URIPath")
    public String URIPath;
}
```

And using these, unmarhaling:

```
Environments environments = JAXB.unmarshal(new File("env.xml"),
    Environments.class);
```

### Elaborating Solution #2

If you want to use a custom `XmlAdapter` to directly get a `Map`, the XML input in its current form cannot be used. It has to be slightly modified to put a wrapper XML element around it. This is required because in Java the `Map` is a property of a class but the `<Environments>` tag is just the wrapper for the `Map`. Example modified XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<wrapper>
  <Environments>
    <Environment Name="A" URIPath="http://a.com" />
    <Environment Name="B" URIPath="http://b.com" />
    <Environment Name="C" URIPath="http://c.com" />
  </Environments>
</wrapper>
```

Taking this as the input XML, here is the solution:

```
class EnvironmentMap {
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = EnvMapAdapter.class)
    @XmlElement(name = "Environments")
    public Map<String, String> envMap;
}

class Environments {
    @XmlElement(name = "Environment")
    public List<Environment> environments;
}

class Environment {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Name")
    public String name;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "URIPath")
    public String uriPath;
}

class EnvMapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Environments, Map<String, String>> {
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> unmarshal(Environments envs) throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (Environment env : envs.environments)
            map.put(env.name, env.uriPath);
        return map;
    }

    @Override
    public Environments marshal(Map<String, String> map) throws Exception {
        Environments environments = new Environments();
        // This method is only called if you marshal (Java -> XML)
        environments.environments = new ArrayList<>(map.size());

        for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            Environment e = new Environment();
            e.name = entry.getKey();
            e.uriPath = entry.getValue();
            environments.environments.add(e);
        }

        return environments;
    }
}
```

And using it:

```
EnvironmentMap envMap = JAXB.unmarshal(new File("env2.xml"),
    EnvironmentMap.class);
System.out.println(envMap.envMap);
```

Which prints:

```
{A=http://a.com, B=http://b.com, C=http://c.com}
```

Comment: Updated with elaborating solution #2. These are working exmaples.